# Script to Set a Formula in Cell When Checkbox is Checked using Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to set a formula in a cell **only** when a checkbox is checked.

So far, the script is as follows, however ends up setting the formula regardless of the checkbox status and doesn't function on the checkbox status.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var cbxRnge = ss.getRange('B3')
  if (cbxRnge == true) {
    return;
  }
  var cell = ss.getRange("D3");
cell.setFormula('=IF(F3=1,"YES","NO")');
}
```

Hoping for the formula to remain in the cell until checkbox is unchecked

**Expected Results**

*Checkbox Unchecked*

[image]

.

*Checkbox Checked*

[image]

**EDIT:**

Have thought to remove the formula when the checkbox is false:

```
  if (cbxRnge == false) {
    return;
  }
  var cell = ss.getRange("D3");
cell.clearContent();
```

however ends up clearing and not returning the function when true.

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qvYYKV3lS2ju4VFRx_4R3_0aMcMlGdGWS3g2LOXKZuk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 12 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    sh.getRange("D13").setFormula("=J13>=1")
  }
}
```